# C++ game, threads and concurrent programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I desperately need some guidance. I need to write a game program of Connect 4 in which concurrent programming with threads will be applied. I need to learn it myself and write such program within a week. I have no idea on how to implement the concurrent part at this moment, and what resources should I look for...Hope you can shed some light on it...

Comment: If you're doing Connect 4 and you *need* threads, I honestly have zero idea what you're doing. The computational requirements of such a game should be basically nothing. Look into an event loop model. Using threads for something as elementary as this sets a bad precedent and will steer you into exponentially increasing complexity with no real gain.

Comment: I have no idea either. That's what the prof gave us and we are told to learn it on our own. I don't even know what resources to look for.

Comment: For a first pass use a container like [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) to push in actions that require attention, and have an event loop that processes these. Define your own event base class and subclass as necessary for things like user interactions or what have you. For a more in-depth introduction, [Game Engine Architecture](http://www.gameenginebook.com/) is the book you want.

Comment: @tadman I think it makes a lot of sense to make the "intelligent" computer player a thread. It emulates how two humans would play. They would constantly be thinking about next move - either while it is their turn or while they wait for opponent. This can be nicely emulated/structured using a thread. The main loop can then concentrate on handling the game, i.e. receive input from the two players and display the result. With a little extra class-work it would be easy make all game combinations, i.e. human vs. human, computer vs. computer or computer vs. human. And with local or remote players.

Comment: @StillLearning I can't agree with that at all. The amount of time to compute the next move should be a millisecond at best, it's absolutely trivial to apply a strategy here. I honestly have no idea what a thread would do for seconds on end other than waste CPU cycles and create enormous complexity.

Comment: @tadman It was part of the homework description (bullet 4). I agree that seconds is overkill

Comment: You can still do that with a rudimentary event loop where if the queue is empty you do a tiny bit of thinking.

Comment: Yes, you can. That's true. But is doesn't scale well for more complicated games.

Comment: @tadman : Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @StillLearning: Thanks for your input.

Comment: @StillLearning Game developers survived for decades without threads by using exactly this strategy. The event loop is absolutely core to most games, and to this day remains the primary driver of most applications. In any case, good answer below for the threaded approach.

Comment: @tadman: I hear you but I do need to complete the assignment with threads, otherwise the prof won't be happy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea seems to be that the computer-player is a thread by it self and that the main thread is handling the game, i.e. coordinating the human player and the robot player.

Below is some (pseudo) code which may help you get started.

```
std::mutex m;
std::queue<int> from_opponent;
std::queue<int> from_robot;

void robotplayer(bool& go_on)
{
    bool wait_for_opponent = true;
    while (go_on)
    {
        int opponents_move;
        while (wait_for_opponent)
        {
            // Spend x milliseconds planning next move
            // ...
            // ...

            m.lock();
            if (!from_opponent.empty())
            {
                opponents_move = from_opponent.front();
                from_opponent.pop();
                wait_for_opponent = false;
            }
            m.unlock();
        }

        // ... calculate robots move
        // ...

        m.lock();
        from_robot.push(row_number);
        m.unlock();   

        wait_for_opponent = true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool go_on = true;

    std::thread robot(robotplayer, go_on);

    while(go_on)
    {
        // Wait for input from user (e.g. via cin)

        // Send move to robot
        m.lock();
        from_opponent.push(row_number);
        m.unlock();   

        // Update display

        // Check for a winner (i.e. set go_on = false)

        // Wait for input from robot

        // Update display

        // Check for a winner (i.e. set go_on = false)
    }

    robot.join();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. You are my hero and you are the only one who answers this question.